# Can't turn on windows defender error code 0x800106ab

Tags: windows-7

Afer downloading Windows updates Window Defender is now reporting Error Code 0x800106ab.  Windows Defender and my BitDefender anti-virus program are turned off.

Answer (score 1):

[Uninstall](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/remove-update#1TC=windows-7) the Update [KB3004394](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3004394/en-us), this [causes the Defender issue](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/windows-update-kb3004394-issues/ace25277-7f65-4486-bc44-c1b106907a18) under Windows 7.

Install the fix from this KB to resolve the issue:

**Install KB3024777 to fix an issue with KB3004394 on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2**
http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/3024777/en-us